# Conditional expression, postgresql, get the result from the case

Tags: postgresql, column-alias

Looking at conditional expressions in Postgresql. To be more precise, [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-conditional.html) example.

```
SELECT * FROM test;

 a
---
 1
 2
 3


SELECT a,
       CASE WHEN a=1 THEN 'one'
            WHEN a=2 THEN 'two'
            ELSE 'other'
       END AS amod
    FROM test;

 a | amod
---+-------
 1 | one
 2 | two
 3 | other
```

I cant seem to find out how to now access the result under amod(one, two and other). After searching around, I haven't been able to find a way to solve it. Any pointers on how to do it?

EDIT: What I'm looking for is to be able to SELECT amod FROM the case expression and get it out as a table.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with that "result"?

Comment: In the same manner as I can SELECT a FROM test, I would like to SELECT amod FROM the result of the case expression.

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate. That solved it. :)